# An online Tomcat application experiences abnormal CPU usage

Tags: java, cpu-usage, tomcat9

An online Tomcat application experiences abnormal CPU usage. Upon inspection using Arthas, it is discovered that the Tomcat poller thread occupies 100% of the CPU. At first, the program was functioning normally, but then the CPU usage suddenly spiked. Afterward, we diverted the traffic away from the problematic instance, but the CPU usage did not alleviate. The Tomcat version is 9.0.68, and the service runs on Kubernetes (k8s).

Has anyone encountered a similar issue? Or is this a bug in Tomcat?

stack

```
"http-nio-8080-Poller" Id=148 cpuUsage=99.97% deltaTime=201ms time=7126264ms RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Poller.run(NioEndpoint.java:799)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```